# React-Redux action.payload is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a beginner in Redux. I'm trying to GET a users list, but when I console.log(action.payload) in reducer function it is showing undefined.

```js
const URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api/'

export function fetchUsers() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchUserRequest());
    return axios.get(`${URL}userdata`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(userlist => fetchedUsersSuccessfully(userlist.data))

  }
}

export function fetchUserRequest() {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_REQUEST',
  }
}
export function fetchedUsersSuccessfully(users) {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_USERS',
    payload: users
  }
}
```

This is my reducer

```js
export function users(state = InitialState, action) {
  console.log(action.payload)
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS:
      return [...state, action.payload]
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you aren't already, I highly recommend you use Redux DevTools Extension for Chrome. It can help you view any changes made to the Redux store as well as record actions as they happen. You can get it here: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Comment: Thx, i will install it.

Comment: @AshrafAli Please add your combinereducers and mapStateToProps

Comment: I'm not dispatching any action at start i.e., not using mapDispatchToProps yet, i just want to get the response of /api/userdata first. `const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users
})

export default rootReducer;`

Answer (score 2):

You've just forgot to dispatch the success action just like you did with the first one. The correct dispatching should be like:

`.then(response => response.json()).then(userlist => dispatch(fetchedUsersSuccessfully(userlist.data)))`

Comment: Did that, but still it is undefined. I'm trying to get this working for a day now.

Comment: Fetch request show correctly? Log the types and see if they are correct. If not, log the `userlist` that you receive from the request, and check if `userlist.data` exists.

Comment: tried to log the types and it shows correctly, but when i log the userlist there is no log output in browser.

Comment: This seems the problem, try to check the network dev tools on your browser. And before that, simulate a correct response, there in `.then(response => response.json())`, put `.then(() => ({ data: [] }))`, if the dispatched action has the array, then there's definitely something wrong with the request.

Comment: should i do that with or without dispatch?

Comment: No matter what i try to log in action function, there is no output. And what do you mean by something wrong with request?.

Comment: The request may be returning `data` undefined, thus, the payload will be surely undefined anyway.

Comment: I have used the same api request with just react and it is working fine though.

Comment: What do you mean by: "but when i log the userlist there is no log output in browser."

Comment: after promise it should return the data right, so i tried to log the userlist to check if i'm indeed getting the user data but there was just no output. Dang Redux is so tough

Comment: So, for me I still understands that there is something wrong in the request flow, because you are seeing no user list returning. Besides that, I can't picture the problem just by the given descriptions, I'd need more visible feedback.

Comment: Tell me what you need. I need to work this out before moving on.

Comment: Tell me what is logged in each step of the Promise chain, and inside the reducer after you dispatch an action.

Comment: `.then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            response.json()})` tried this action, but the browser doesn't log anything.

Comment: Also tried this.`export function fetchUsers(){
    const request = axios.get(`${URL}userdata`)
    console.log(request)
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS,
        payload: request
    }
}`  But the browser doesn't log, even the promise.

Comment: This was supposed to give a syntax error, put a semicolon between ( ; ) the expressions, between the console.log and the response.json. So, if it still keeps not logging anything to the console, this means that the Promise returning from `axios.get(`${URL}userdata`)` isn't resolving. But put the semicolon first, test and report.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. Link to image https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArverjoG11pUgekW3WZCpS4fnpcAwQ     https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArverjoG11pUgekVFz-wqalLtpZdxA

Comment: This is definitely problem with the request, otherwise you would see the response being logged, the `get` from `axios` isn't resolving. I don't see any request to localhost:3001 for json (there's only one for the document) in the network profiler. Swap for a moment this axios for the `fetch` api, just use `fetch` instead of axios.get.

Comment: Tried fetch too. But still there was nothing. I will try it again anyway.Additional info: I'm running my server and also tried with my react without redux and it is working fine there.

Comment: But do you have a server for port 3001 and another for 3000? Because the `URL` of the get points to port 3001 and on the picture you showed you're accessing the server through 3000. Anyway, I can't help more, unfortunately, one thing is sure is that the problem is with the request fired.

Comment: No, but i'm using cors to get around that. Thx for your time

Answer (score 1):

When a store is created, an "INIT" action is dispatched. So all reducer return their initial value. By this your initial state tree is populated. 
So if you are getting the undefined error, it can be due to @@INIT actions which has no payload.

Plus, whenever you dispatch an action, all of your reducers are called, your fetchUserRequest action has no payload, so you get undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the api was returning a response into data and I was checking into a variable , Fix was to directly use Object of your Response model in api call.

```
Action:

getPaidMarketingOnlyPiadMarketingDataSuccess: (state, action: PayloadAction<MarketingOnlyPaidMarketingData>) => {
  debugger;
  state.paidMarketingOnlyData = action.payload;
  state.loading = false;
}



//OLD

  dispatch(paidMarketingSlice.actions.getPaidMarketingOnlyPiadMarketingDataSuccess(data.marketingOnlyPaidMarketingData));




//OLD 

 const getPaidMarketingOverviewData = (params: 
 GetPaidMarketingOverviewDataRequest) =>
 vennFlowApi.get<{ marketingOnlyPaidMarketingData: 
 MarketingOnlyPaidMarketingData}>(
 '/MarketingOnlyPaidMarketing/MarketingOnlyPaidMarketing',
 {
   params,
 },
 );



 //WORKING 
  const getPaidMarketingOverviewData = (params: 
  GetPaidMarketingOverviewDataRequest) =>
  vennFlowApi.get< MarketingOnlyPaidMarketingData>(
  '/MarketingOnlyPaidMarketing/MarketingOnlyPaidMarketing',
  {
    params,
  },
  );


 dispatch(paidMarketingSlice.actions.getPaidMarketingOnlyPiadMarketingDataSuccess(data));
```